# Get the pictures of the facebook profile album

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

thank you for your time and help.

I am trying to get all the profile pictures of the current user , but I am getting a weird answer :

```
{Response: responseCode:200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"data":[]}}, error: null, isFromCache: false}
```

I have already made the authentification and loaded some other informations successfully.

I have already checked some other similar questions/answers and I didn't find anyone working with fql and the new API of facebook.

The permissions are defined like this:

```
/**
 * the list of permissions of facebook
 * */
private static final List<String> FACEBOOK_PERMISSION_LIST = Arrays.asList(
        "user_photos", "email", "user_birthday", "basic_info");
```

The code

```
String fqlQuery = "SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE album_object_id IN (SELECT object_id  FROM album WHERE owner = me() AND name='Profile Pictrue' AND type='profile' )";
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("q", fqlQuery);

Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
Request request = new Request(session, "/fql",
                        params, HttpMethod.GET,
                        new Request.Callback() {
                                public void onCompleted(
                                    Response response) {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "Got results: "
                                                + response.toString());
                                    }
                                });
                        Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

I hope you can help me, every suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in `name='Profile Pictrue'`; it's `name='Profile Pictures'`

(But the thing is that you dont need to check for this `name`, `type=profile` is just enough.)

So your final query should be:

```
SELECT src_big
FROM photo
WHERE album_object_id IN (
    SELECT object_id 
    FROM album
    WHERE owner = me() 
    AND type='profile'
)
```

or better (because it was not possible to query by type for me):

```
String fqlQuery = "SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE album_object_id IN (SELECT object_id  FROM album WHERE owner = me()  AND (type='profile' OR name='Profile Pictures'))";
```

And adding some parameters to the request, which will look like this:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
params.putString("format", "json");
params.putString("query", fqlQuery);
params.putString("access_token", fbAccessToken);
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
Request request = new Request(session, "/fql", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Got results: " + response.toString());
    }
});
Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot , it is not working with the type, but working with the name. So I optimised a little the request :

String fqlQuery = "SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE album_object_id IN (SELECT object_id  FROM album WHERE owner = me()  AND (type='profile' OR name='Profile Pictures'))";
and added some parameters to the request :
Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("format", "json");
        params.putString("query", fqlQuery);
        params.putString("access_token", fbAccessToken);